# How should a bower package written in typescript be structured?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bower, typescript-typings

I am writing a bower package in typescript that is to be consumed in-house. It references some bowered in libraries such as angular and the typings for these are obtained using typings and definitely typed. It also references some in-house libraries that are also bowered in.

At the moment, I can see that my bower package needs to include my js and my typings in an index.d.ts file. I understand that anyone that consumes my package will need to do a typings install to get the typings for angular etc. but what do I do for the typings for the in-house libraries? How do I make it easy?

I have something like this:

```
MYBowerComponent
|_ bower_components
   |_ angular
   |_ inhousecomponent1
   |_ inhousecomponent2
   |_ inhousecomponent3
|_ dist
   |_ my_bower_component.js
   |_ index.d.ts
   |_ bower.json
|_ app
   |_ (a load of ts code)
   |_ app.ts
   |_ references.ts
|_ typings
   |_ globals
      |_ (angular etc)
   |_ index.d.ts
```

Where app/references.ts includes any references to inhousecomponent1, inhousecomponent2 and inhousecomponent3 AND a reference to typings/index.d.ts.
dist/index.d.ts includes the typings for my js.

Broadly, I can see that the answer is to a) somehow allow the consumers to install the typings of my in-house libraries OR b) to include the contents of reference.d.ts in dist/index.d.ts.

Is a) possible? If b) is the recommended approach how do I handle the relative paths in the references? Or, is there a better way?

Thanks,

Adam